# AWS - Lambda Python - Only Returning the example code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hey I am looking for help on why this is happening. So in AWS Lambda the example code has a function which returns a ~ status and message of "hello lambda". When I use my sample code (below) it will still return the same response no matter what I put in my code.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    print("Hello World")
    return {
        "status":"Good"
        }
```

The only response I get is:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Request ID:
"8e2957c8-ebb3-41f8-935b-4bb699f18eaa"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 8e2957c8-ebb3-41f8-935b-4bb699f18eaa Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 8e2957c8-ebb3-41f8-935b-4bb699f18eaa
REPORT RequestId: 8e2957c8-ebb3-41f8-935b-4bb699f18eaa  Duration: 1.19 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB
```

I should be expecting at least the status to say "Good".

I have made sure I saved the python file within lambda before running the test event. I have no idea what is happening and why it will only return the sample result.

Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: Are you doing all of this within the Lambda console? Did you deploy the changes?

Comment: You are probably not deploying your function, or executing old version of it if you use versioning in lambda.

Answer (score 0):

As @jarmod and @Marcin pointed out you still need to use the "Deploy" button for the changes to work within Lambda. Thank you both!